# Bluetooth Does not Find headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I used my headphones on Bluetooth daily until yesterday, when I could not connect them on Bluetooth. I thought I could just "forget" the device and add them again, but since then Bluetooth does not even find them. I figured out that any device that I forget in Bluetooth, becomes undiscoverable. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possibly an hardware failure. How does it work in a live session?